# WASM on Uno into established Xamarin Forms Solution - gives SPA error no index.html

Tags: xamarin.forms, webassembly, uno-platform

I added a WASM project head to my existing 70 page Xamarin Forms app; the UWP works fine once I copy the images into it but big trouble getting WASM to work: gives SPA error re missing index.html.

To quote:

> InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__1(HttpContext context, Func next)

The UWP version runs correctly and I know WASM relies on that; does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this?

What would be stopping the Build from writing into the dist folder? (under the bin\debug\netstandard2.0 folder.

Using vs2019 community edition, v16.9.4 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Martin, I just ran into the same issue.  Did you ever find a solution?